# How do we create object literals from arrays of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-objects

How do we create object literals from arrays of object in javascript ? , so that I can access name using a value or a number like for example I have literal object which is

#literal sample object

```
SAMPLE_LITERALS {
  '1': 'Sample1',
  '2': 'Sample2',
  '3': 'Sample3',
  '4': 'Sample4'
}
```

then I can access a value for example  `SAMPLE_LITERALS[4]` and the result would be Sample4.

I wanted to implement like that on my array of object sample below. Help would be appricated. Thank you.

I wanted to access the name .

#Code Query

```
 const team = await TeamsModel.findAll({
    where: {
      deletedAt: { [Op.eq]: null },
    },
  });
```

#result

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Admin",
            "createdAt": "2019-12-10T07:01:16.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-12-10T07:01:16.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "createdById": null,
            "updatedById": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Customer Support",
            "createdAt": "2019-12-10T07:01:16.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-12-10T07:01:16.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "createdById": null,
            "updatedById": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null
        },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(result.map(obj => [obj.name, obj]))`

Comment: Your first snippet is an object and you may access its property values by keyname. Your second data structure is array of object, you may access its elements, using `Array.prototype.find()` or by index of the item. If your goal is array-like object for the second structure, you may use `Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(o => ({[o.id]: o})))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to index on `id`, this is a pretty simple way to do that:

```js
const teamsAsObject = {};
teams.forEach(team => {
  teamsAsObject[team.id] = team;
});
```

Comment: `TeamsModel.findAll({where: {deletedAt: { [Op.eq]: null }}})` certainly does not look as though we're trying to index by `id`.

Comment: my goal is to access name value from the array of objects using id

Comment: @Michael Pratt , for example then I can access out side the loop the value like TEAM_NAME[1] and the value would be Admin

Comment: Is `Code Query` then irrelevant to your question?  If you just want to collect the `name` property from the data represented as `result`, that's quite simple: `teams.map(t => t.name)`.  I thought you were looking for more.

Comment: If you for some reason want just a list of team names, then @ScottSauyet's code will work for you. If you want to access all properties on the team object, however, you'd need to have one list for each property, which (in my opinion) would not be ideal. I'd suggest using my solution to create one map and access properties that way: `teamsAsObject[1].name`